# Where is the wallet account data stored?

Tags: wallet

Saw the duplicate question "[What is saved in wallet.dat exactly?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63136/what-is-saved-in-wallet-dat-exactly)" and found they not say anything about account. I guess the wallet account data should stored in wallet.dat too, am I right?

Comment: what do you mean by "wallet account data"?

Comment: Sorry, It's should be "data about bitcoin coin wallet's account system"